# Errors were encountered while processing: amdgpu-dkms & warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel?

Tags: kernel, amdgpu-pro

I was trying to install AMD graphics driver via `amdgpu-install` script for my fresh Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS install and encountered an error saying:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.2.4-1646729.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up libx32gcc-11-dev (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:23.2.0.50700-1646729.22.04) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:23.2.0.50700-1646729.22.04) ...
Setting up libx32stdc++-11-dev (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up lib32gcc-11-dev (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up lib32stdc++-11-dev (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (1:5.7.50700-1646729.22.04) ...
Setting up rocm-language-runtime (5.7.0.50700-45~22.04) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (1:5.7.50700-1646729.22.04) ...
Setting up gcc-11-multilib (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up gcc-multilib (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up rocm-opencl-runtime (5.7.0.50700-45~22.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/rocm-5.7.0/bin/clinfo to provide /usr/bin/clinfo (clinfo) in auto mode
Setting up g++-11-multilib (11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) ...
Setting up g++-multilib (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up hipcc (1.0.0.50700-45~22.04) ...
Setting up hip-dev (5.7.31921.50700-45~22.04) ...
Setting up hip-runtime-amd (5.7.31921.50700-45~22.04) ...
Setting up rocm-hip-runtime (5.7.0.50700-45~22.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/rocm-5.7.0/bin/rocm_agent_enumerator to provide /usr/bin/rocm_agent_enumerator (rocm_agent_enumerator) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /opt/rocm-5.7.0/bin/rocminfo to provide /usr/bin/rocminfo (rocminfo) in auto mode
Processing triggers for install-info (6.8-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I look at the `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.2.4-1646729.22.04/build/make.log` I get a warning saying:

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-6.2.4-1646729.22.04 for kernel 6.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Prş 02 Kas 2023 19:40:09 +03
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  You are using:           gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
```

I was unable to solve problem. Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [edit] your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you were installing and how it was installed.

Comment: I edited the post. Ubuntu 22.04.3. And I installed it through the installer on live image.

Comment: A bit late but since no one answered this question, I had to come up with a solution: Just install amdgpu-install script with --no-dkms option first, then install the whole script. This way the problem solved for me.